# why CreateRemoteThread cause inject target crash

Tags: visual-c++

Update on 2019/11/19:
I search google and find a lib to do this(I can't remember which is it now), and it works fine.

Update on 2019/6/19:

My env is win10, the reason is this code is not work on win10?

Origin:

I use this code to just inject `int foo() {return 0}` to a target process. But It cause target process crash.

The entire vs solution is here: https://github.com/huhuang03/test/tree/master/win/InjectHelloWorld. Include the InjectMe and InjectByCode.

```
    char hand_asm[100] = {0xC3}; // 0xc3 is the retn assembly
    if (!WriteProcessMemory(h_target, targetFuncSpace, &hand_asm, CODE_SPACE_SIZE, NULL)) {
        showError(L"Cna't write targetFuncSpace");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    InjectFuncParam param;
    LPVOID injectFuncParamSpace = VirtualAllocEx(h_target, NULL, sizeof(param), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (!injectFuncParamSpace) {
        showError(L"Can't alloc injectFuncParamSpace");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    system("pause");
    DWORD remoteThreadId = 0;
    HANDLE h_remoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(h_target, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)targetFuncSpace, injectFuncParamSpace, 0, &remoteThreadId);
    if (!h_remoteThread) {
        VirtualFreeEx(h_target, injectFuncParamSpace, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        VirtualFreeEx(h_target, targetFuncSpace, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        showError(L"Cant' create rmeote Thread");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

this cause InjectMe crash, I can't find a way to debug this.

By the way, I use ollydbg to set a breakpoint at `targetFuncSpace`, but the ollydbg says it's not code segment... Why, I had use the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` to alloc the space.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is you can't VirtualFree targetFuncSpace until the remote thread in the target process has finished executing.

Also WriteProcessMemory is copying CODE_SPACE_SIZE (4096) bytes from hand_asm which is only 100 bytes.